# Completely disconnecting monitor when rendering

Tags: windows-10, display, gpu, rendering, cinema4d

In my pc, I render animations with octane renderer. I often leave it overnight on. I want to completely disconnect the monitor from pc. In this case, is disconnecting it from the gpu through hdmi will cause potentially any problem? Or it suffices to just turn off the monitor? Why or why not should I compeletely disconnect the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

> Or it suffices to just turn off the monitor?

Yes.

I can't think of any good reason to physically disconnect the HDMI cable.